# listSort function written in c works wrong

Tags: c, list, selection-sort

I've wrriten a funcrtion that sorts linked list using SelectionSort method. But I have a bug in my logic but can't work in out. What I foudn out from debugger is that the second for-loop becomes an infinite loop after second iteration. But I can't understand why. In debugger I see that there is NULL in the last node in  list.

```
void listSort(node_pointer node) {

for (; node != NULL; node = node->next)
{
    node_pointer min = node;
    printf("node: %d\n", node);
    for (node_pointer j = node->next; j != NULL; j = j->next) {

        printf("next node address%d \n", node);
        if (j->value < min->value) {
            min = j;

        }

        node_pointer tmp = node;
        node = min;
        tmp->next = node->next; 
        min->next = tmp; 

    }

}
```

}

here is all the code if needed:

http://pastebin.com/NaUMtLv2

Answer (score 1):

You are swapping the nodes inside inner for loop, which is wrong. In selection sort, the swapping is done in the outer for loop. The logic is as follows: We select an element, considering it as the min, then we compare all the next following elements to it to find the minimum value. Then we swap this new min value with originally considered min element. Thus, the correct code would be:

```
void listSort(node_pointer node) {

    for (; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
        node_pointer min = node;
        printf("node: %d\n", node);

        for (node_pointer j = node->next; j != NULL; j = j->next) {
            printf("next node address%d \n", node);
            if (j->value < min->value) {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        node_pointer tmp;
        //Swap only values, no need to break the structure of nodes
        tmp->value = node->value;
        node->value = min->value;
        min->value = tmp->value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that you swap the values like that.  It is certainly doable here in C with simple data types for the values; it is not so clear that it is a good idea in all circumstances, or that it translates well to C++, for example.  However, those are somewhat hypothetical scenarios — what you've got should work (though I've not tested it myself).

Comment: Yes you are right, my solution is appropriate for simple data types only. I focused more on how selection sort works, rather than the swapping of nodes, because if we directly swap nodes, we have to take extra care to maintain the chain of nodes

Comment: `node_pointer tmp;` --> `node_pointer tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));`.. `free(tmp);`

Comment: `printf("node: %d\n", node);` --> `printf("node: %p\n", (void*)node);`